# how to create params in django url?

Tags: django

I have a django project where url is like this

```
url(r'^invoice/(?P<invoice_id>[A-Za-z0-9]+)/(?P<order_id>[A-Za-z0-9]+)$',GenerateInvoicePdf,name='invoice'),
```

which generates url `localhost:8000/invoice/2341wq23fewfe1231/3242`

but i want url to be like `localhost:8000/invoice?invoice_id=2341wq23fewfe1231&order_id=3242`

i tried documentation and used syntax like this `re_path(r'^comments/(?:page-(?P<page_number>\d+)/)?$', comments),` But did not get desired result.

how can i do so?

Comment: If you're using Django 2.0 + you can change your URL patterns so they don't need to have regex in them.

Answer (score 3):

The parts which you are trying to write after `?` is called [url query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). You don't need to define them in the `urls.py`. You can just use:

```
re_path(r'^comments/$', comments),
```

And inside comments views, you can access the query string like this:

```
def comments(request):
    invoice_id = request.GET.get('invoice_id')
    order_id = request.GET.get('order_id')
    # rest of the code
```